# Efficient way to get Account age?

Tags: account, getsignaturesforaddress, block-time

So right now I'm calling getSignatures and getting blocktime of the earliest one I get returned. Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: I could be wrong but unless you stored the creation time in the account data, there is no accurate way of getting the account age from the chain itself.

Comment: Yea I think youre right thats why Im doing it this way to get a rough estimation. I guess Ill keep doing it this way as I dont need it to be that accurate its for ui purposes only. This is for some nfts so Ive added timestamp field on offchain data.